# Utorren't won't start with Wine

Tags: wine, utorrent

Yesterday due to a problem i had,I reinstalled Ubuntu.Before the reinstall,starting Utorrent with Wine worked,but now it doesn't anymore,I click on the utorrent.exe and nothing happens,it's like I don't even click on it.What could be the problem?

Comment: Why do you need utorrent?  Loads of native Linux torrent applications.  I used to use utorrent, once I moved to Ubuntu, I started using Transmission and never looked back.

Comment: I'm a new Ubuntu user,started using it only a few days ago...discovered Transmission only today,after posting this message xD. I always used utorrent and wanted to use it here as well,but Transmission does the trick,will stick to it from now on.Thanks for the reply.

Comment: There is also utorrent for Linux, it's still not stable, closed source like the Windows client (I dislike the idea of having such a program running that uploads a lot of data into the Internet and being closed source) and doesn't come with a native GUI (uses Web UI instead). http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/utorrent-is-finally-available-for-linux.html

Comment: in my opinion deluge is also a good torrent client

Comment: @LiveWireBT it's also controlled by the music labels, it's intrusive and using it you allow utorrent to track data, hack into your computer and use your personal data.

Comment: Utorrent is pure spyware and it's just a back door for major companies to hack into your computer, you can even spot that by simply looking at the TCP/IP traffic on your connection, or simply read [the terms of use](http://www.utorrent.com/legal/terms-of-use) especially the point number 7.
It's used by people that wants to be tracked and don't care about nothing. Just use anything but utorrent or any bittorent product.

Comment: @girardengo That is true, I just recently found out that development of this client changed from desktop GUI only to libtorrent-rasterbar based CLI, Web and desktop GUI. I was very positively surprised.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have Wine set as a default.  You can right click on it and go to properties and Open With.  You also have to hit other applications and select the version of Wine that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

My shortcut to open utorrent runs `wine /home/<myuser>/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/uTorrent/utorrent_2.0.4.exe /NOINSTALL`

I forget where I found that out from, but if I remember correctly it didn't work without the /NOINSTALL switch.

Obviously you'll need to change which exe it runs as mine is utorrent version 2.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried transmission bit-torrent client?

```
sudo aptitude install transmission
```